# I am working on project server 2019 the Timehseet API did not work here is the link of the apis and the test result with the postman

Tags: sharepoint, postman, project-server, ms-project-server-2016

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
        <m:code>-2146232060, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
        <m:message xml:lang="fr-FR">Exception de HRESULT : 0x80131904</m:message>
    </m:error>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKV4v.png)

Comment: API-LINK====>https://github.com/akordowski/Project-Server-Resources/blob/master/Project%20Server%20REST%20API%20Endpoints.md

Comment: ,may be try removing ne slash from //timesheet